# Is CSS giving error?

Tags: html, css, dom

At a recent interview I was asked the question "**Is CSS giving error?**" by the interviewer.

Is there an interpreter working behind CSS which blocks execution of the program? Or can we say that CSS does not give any error? I am still confused as to what is the answer to this question because the interviewer also did not say anything.

Comment: Sounds like the interviewer "is giving error"

Comment: Maybe he was thinking about some CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS?

Comment: I haven't seen CSS throwing any error.

Comment: CSS Prepropecessors thought throw errors cause there is a js or ruby engine behind it to convert it to plain css.

Comment: This strikes me a s a very odd question, especially phrased like that. Maybe the interviewer was thinking about css validation?

Comment: Invalid CSS is just ignored. This is by design. In other words, CSS never gives you any errors. Browser developer tools are able to tell you if there is anything that it does not understand, but that will never affect the page itself.

Comment: In console, If a background image path is incorrect it will show an error like: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: @om. That is not CSS throwing error. That is the browser giving error because it could not load the resource.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the question is too broad and not specific.
This is how I  would have  answered the question.

> **Is CSS giving error ?**

Depends on the place you are looking at.
In a IDE? sure it will show you validation errors. 
In browser? Most browsers tend to ignore CSS validation errors and continue with rest of the rules.Again as @Kishan Choudhary mentioned in another answer "CSS" refers just the styling language and languages cannot prompt you errors by themselves.

Alt. Question: How can we validate/debug/find errors in a CSS?

> **Can we say that CSS does not give any error?**

Again it depends on the place you are looking at.
In development environment? Yes almost all web IDEs will help you to find your CSS mistakes.

In Client browser? Not so much,You can open browser console/developer tool if available and there might be logs errors, for example invalid or unreachable URLs of images you have used in CSS. Again is it a CSS syntax or validation error?nope

> **Is there an interpreter working behind CSS which blocks execution of**
>   **the program?**

Yes every browser has an inbuilt CSS interpreter/parser following W3C standards and does it like to block execution?No,normal behavior of all most all browsers is to that ignore (not to block interpreting and applying  remaining valid style rules) CSS validation errors and continue with rest of the rules.

### Update: W3 Guidelines Handling CSS Parsing Errors

**Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification**

[4.2 Rules for handling parsing errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors)

> In some cases, **user agents must ignore** part of an illegal style sheet.
>   This specification defines ignore to mean that the user agent parses
>   the illegal part (in order to find its beginning and end), but
>   otherwise acts as if it had not been there. CSS 2.1 reserves for
>   future updates of CSS all property:value combinations and @-keywords
>   that do not contain an identifier beginning with dash or underscore.
>   Implementations must ignore such combinations (other than those
>   introduced by future updates of CSS).
>
> To ensure that new properties and new values for existing properties
>   can be added in the future.

**CSS Syntax Module Level 3**

[2.2. Error Handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#error-handling)

> When errors occur in CSS, the parser attempts to **recover gracefully**,
>   throwing away only the minimum amount of content before returning to
>   parsing as normal. This is because errors aren’t always mistakes - new
>   syntax looks like an error to an old parser, and it’s useful to be
>   able to add new syntax to the language without worrying about
>   stylesheets that include it being completely broken in older UAs.

Answer (score 38):

CSS itself will not give an error, however CSS which has an error in its syntax will not render correctly.  The browser may not be able to understand what is meant at a given point, and therefore not be able to format the page correctly.

There's also a difference in CSS being syntactically correct, where everything is properly enclosed and lines terminated, and it being standards compliant according to the W3C specification.

EDIT : (example for syntax correctness and standards compliance)
The following is an example of syntactically correct CSS, which won't fail validation on the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/):

```
p.my-class {
  color : red;
  -moz-border-radius : 3px;
}
```

Whilst this is technically valid CSS, according to the [vendor specific extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords) section of the CSS 2.1 syntax, they should be avoided.  It's the initial dash or underscore which lets them be valid.

Comment: what do you mean in the second paragraph?

Comment: @FarzadYZ I've added an example to show what I mean in that paragraph.

Comment: Why do the interpreters or parsers for most programming languages give error message output, but browsers/css do not? I'd really like to know. Don't the css developers feel that error messages would help in debugging, as they do in other languages? So confused.

Answer (score 16):

Generally errors in the CSS doesn't cause any error messages in the browser. Any incorrect code is simply ignored (or in some cases accepted by assuming a missing part, e.g. a length unit).

The CSS parser tries to recover after each incorrect code, so usually it will only affect the style or the rule where the error is, the parser won't just stop parsing the rest of the CSS code.

Some browsers will add warnings to the error console for errors in the CSS, so developers can open the console to see if there is any errors.

Comment: Can you give an example of where the browser *assumes a missing part, e.g. a length unit*, other than 0?

Comment: @torazaburo: Internet Explorer in quirks mode assumes pixels if there is no unit.

Answer (score 14):

> Is CSS giving error ?

Yes, any rule which cannot be understood by CSS parser will lead to an error. In general any data which cannot be handled by a system/program will lead to an error. But how the system finally handles that error is your question and it can be

1. Ignore the error and continue to process.
2. Halt the process.

The **CSS parser will not halt** on an  error. It just puts an **error log** to the console if it finds any invalid css property which cannot be parsed/ mentioned in [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/) and ignores(1) all the css-rule data till it finds next `;`.

As w3c.org doc says

> A UA must **skip a declaration** with an invalid property name or an
>   invalid value.

Here UA(User Agent) means browser in our case. So the invalid css keys/values has to be skipped and the browser vendor may choose to show error in devtools/firebug to help developers to fix it. Also it is browser vendor dependent to put error logs or not.

Answer (score 9):

Some browsers will report CSS errors in the console. Firefox comes to mind.

```
<style> foo { bar: baz; } </style>
```

results in the error:

> Unknown property 'bar'.  Declaration dropped. css-error.html:2:11

However, this will not "block execution of the program".

To my knowledge, no similar feature exists in Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

In the CSS there is no errors but you can face some errors in the browser's console,
That could be the browser giving error but not CSS throwing error.

Answer (score 8):

I think the "Is CSS giving error?" statement is ambiguous, but let's first take a look at [this link (CSS 2.1 Specification)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-CSS21-20050613/css2.pdf), jump to **4.2 Rules for handling parsing errors**

The specification explicitly specifies how parsing errors should be ignored, in fact, it says:

```
This specification
defines ignore to mean that the user agent parses the illegal part (in order to find
its beginning and end), but otherwise acts as if it had not been there
```

In fact, in same cases it even specifies how to turn an invalid piece of css into a valid one:

```
User agents must close all open constructs (for example: blocks, parentheses,
brackets, rules, strings, and comments) at the end of the stylesheet. For
example:

@media screen {
  p:before { content: ’Hello

would be treated the same as:

@media screen {
  p:before { content: ’Hello’; }
}
```

So looking from this perspective, CSS never "gives" errors, because any errors will be effectively parsed and fixed or ignored, but will never stop execution of the rules nor the parser.

However, if you have one developer talking to another in front of an IDE, I think it would be fair enough to ask "Is the CSS giving errors" referring to the IDE's messages and in fact, if we look at a [CSS parser project](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) we can clearly see in the documentation that the parser **can** give error messages, it's just browsers that were directly instructed to ignore errors.

Answer (score 5):

CSS is not a real programming language but a domain-specific language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

In contrast to scripting languages like JavaScript or PHP (which are Turing-complete programming languages) as well as real programming languages like Java or C CSS will not "give errors" as CSS-code is not real program source code.

However as any domain specific language CSS has a syntax and is read by an interpreter (very similar to a declarative Turing-complete programming language).

If the syntax is not correct (test here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) the CSS is invalid. It depends on the interpreter used how to deal with invalid CSS parts, interpreters in common Web browsers will not halt on CSS syntax errors.

This question therefore can not be explicitly answered:

- CSS can be invalid (syntax)
- CSS can have "syntax errors"
- CSS will not "give" errors and errors are usually just ignored by common interpreters

Answer (score 5):

@om. yes it can block your program but in very rear cases. For example if you relay on the width of the element and if you set a display:none to the element and did not make a case to return undefined your application will stuck because your parameter will not have a value.

So it can prevent the execution with interference with other languages.

However how other say in their answers, only css can trow a error for missing file or something like this, but it will not stop the execution of the application.

But i have seen a problem when css property can make a jquery method not working properly and for this the jquery throw error and stop the execution of the application.

Comment: This example would be a bug/error in your application and not a CSS parsing error.

Comment: @IMI you are right but in this case it will stop the execution of the program. The author ask "Is there an interpreter working behind CSS which blocks execution of the program?" And I got a idea when i spot this to happen it is not a interpreter and i have listed the situation in which can have conflict. See what i have write that the css can leave to a problem when you relay on it on very rare reasons. But the answer if only the css can trow a error and prevent the application to contunue is NO it cannot happen.

Answer (score 4):

css can block program in such a way, if you have button and some css properties are **not allowing it to display well** on your page, in that case we can say it is blocking, otherwise **it is not blocker** for execution.
even errors don't block the execution, it just **misplace or display the things improperly**.

Answer (score 4):

The answers depends on how you define **Error**.

> 1. If **Error** means happening of something unexpected, then CSS surely gives errors, cause, it wont work if you have something wrong in the syntax.
> 2. If **Error** means throwing something to browser or console, CSS doesn't do so.
> 3. If **Error** means something which breaks the workflow and stops the execution of the next part of codes, CSS doesn't.

If you consider point 2 and 3, you may consider CSS errors like warnings in PHP or other programming languages. Only difference is that, in PHP we have option to turn them on to throw something in the browser. CSS doesn't have any such option till now.

Answer (score 3):

CSS rendering is a process of the browser (or similar) and is intended to not "throw an error" (exception, etc). ...In theory.

*(bugs in libs/dependencies could cause true errors such as a certain combination of characters freaking out the greater OS. These bugs are well documented on all operating systems and beyond but operate on the fringe of this inquiry)*

I have read many times, from many sources, that each browser desires a compliant CSS feature and does their best to "absorb" bad or mistake riddled syntax recovering as promptly as possible. Having a CSS interpreter hang (error) is totally possible, but I always think of the final implementation of CSS parsing as a flavor of a major anti-pattern in Python:

```
# bad code, just some theory, my Python code "always works"
try:
    # code
except:
    pass
```

where any and all errors are swallowed.

As others have stated, "Is CSS giving error?" is a bad or possibly trick question. CSS is syntax or language.

So here's the real deal: **Language gives no errors and has no capacity for error**. Only the interpretation of the language may errors be provided (as a product of evaluation). Only the evaluation has the capacity to find error.

If the term "parser" was added to the question then YES, the CSS parser is giving error. But as the phrase stands in your (un-edited) post, I would answer with some linguistic whoop-a$$ and a little CS-101: No, here's why...

Just my $0.02 from a Programmer + Linguist.

Comment: This is a slightly academic distinction. By your logic, we cannot say that JS throws errors, only that the JS interpreter throws errors while interpreting the JS. But it's also incorrect to say that the *CSS parser is giving error*. In fact, the whole point, and answer to the question, is that it **doesn't**.

Comment: @torazaburo I agree, semantics in reality. Having done many interviews and been interviewed far too much, I don't like trick or junk questions and some of the various dirty programmer tricks. Your statement of "it doesn't" is apropos in so far as the answer is neither Yes or No but the other option in boolean logic "not set" aka null or what ever your language may use. I still advocate standing your ground on junk questions, and I think this was such an example.

Answer (score 3):

"Is CSS giving error ?" - No

CSS itself don't gives error. It will just ignore that attribute if it is incorrect. If there is syntax error then it will also ignore the same and if any other selector get effected due to syntax error (like missing of '}') that also will be ignored.

There are various IDE (like visual studio) highlight your errors. 
As gabe3886 told you can also validate your syntax using [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Answer (score 3):

NO, CSS never gives an error. You will not be able to see any error in console or anywhere caused by CSS.

As CSS is just styling language and if something doesn't get styled as expected it will not be reported as error.

To note that we have buggy CSS code we will have to look at the page and some elements on the page will be get rendered as expected. There are some tricks to Debug your CSS code.

Answer (score 3):

html is a markup language, it does not contains errors so as css
if there is something gone wrong, it tries to show what is right upto the mark
css has no errors, but ***warnings*** as we can see in console that specific properties are ***invalid***

like using `-webkit-` while viewing in `safari` or `mozilla`

Answer (score 3):

No, "CSS does not give error," but I think that the interviewer may have been mis-stating the question.

If the interviewer was not mis-stating the question, then we can definitively say that no, CSS does not give errors.  There is no evaluator or compiler in the CSS spec that scans your cascade looking for errors.  It could even be argued that *browsers* do not have error handling for CSS, as all commonly used browsers actually discard erroneously written declarations and then search for the nearest semi-colon, and then go back to the reading cascade.

[Tab Atkins Jr has a good explanation of how browsers handle errors in CSS](http://www.xanthir.com/blog/b4JF0) and why they handle them that way.

> If the browser is in trying to parse a declaration and it encounters something it doesn't understand, it throws away the declaration, then seeks forward until it finds a semicolon that's not inside of a {}, [], or () block.

So if the interviewer was trying to play gotcha with this question, I think you could confidently answer that no, CSS is not giving error.  But, there's a decent chance that the interviewer may not really understand CSS or how browsers interpret CSS and wants you to find the errors in a block of CSS.  Never be shy to ask an interviewer what they might mean when they ask a question, or if it doesn't sound clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is *CSS* giving error?
>   Does CSS work on its own with it's own separated "compiler"?

Sure, NOT, as for CSS the browser is the component of the execution process that gives errors while CSS on its own cant.

> Example

```
#foo{
    Bar: 50%;
    Nonsense: 100%;
    color: red
    }
```

In this case the browser will ignore the Bar ans Nonsense proprieties and jump to color propriety. And **you will have no Exception or error thrown**, unlike *JS* (just for comparison).
So the obvious answer is No!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, exactly right sometime CSS can also giving Error, But it is not through an error, instead of it stop the styling after where the Syntax has an error.

**CSS**

```
.myClass {
    color : red
    background-color : green;
}
```

> This code will giving error, while the code will not execute in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the conclusion I can say in @Kishan Choudhary's words "Is CSS giving error ?" - No

but there may be parsing and browser giving errors.

These points are help me to got conclusion.

1. CSS itself will not give an error. (@gabe3886)
2. Generally errors in the CSS doesn't cause any error messages in the browser. Any incorrect code is simply ignored
   The specification explicitly specifies how parsing errors should be ignored. (@Guffa)
3. The CSS parser will not halt on an error. It just puts an error log to the console if it finds any invalid css property which cannot be parsed/ mentioned in specs and ignores(1) all the css-rule data till it finds next ;. (@rajuGT)
4. The invalid css keys/values has to be skipped and the browser vendor may choose to show error in devtools/firebug to help developers to fix it. (@rajuGT)
5. "Is CSS giving error ?" - No | CSS itself don't gives error. It will just ignore that attribute if it is incorrect. (@Kishan Choudhary)
6. However as any domain specific language CSS has a syntax and is read by an interpreter (very similar to a declarative Turing-complete programming language). (@Blackbam)
7. Yes it can block your program but in very rear cases. (@George Plamenov Georgiev)
8. CSS never "gives" errors, because any errors will be effectively parsed and fixed or ignored, but will never stop execution of the rules nor the parser. (@Eduardo Wada)
9. Yeah, exactly right sometime CSS can also giving Error, But it is not through an error, instead of it stop the styling after where the Syntax has an error. (@Kamal Kumar)
10. Most browsers tend to ignore CSS validation errors and continue with rest of the rules. (@DeshanR)
11. In console, If a background image path is incorrect it will show an error like: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (@om)
12. @om, That is not CSS throwing error. That is the browser giving error because it could not load the resource. (@Farzad YZ)

Thanks guys.