# When I Add The float:right; Into The .nav Css The Header Disappears. Any Fixes?

Tags: html, css

I'm very New To `CSS` And `HTML`. This Was Just A Test Website for A Header And I Was Trying To Move Text In The Header. When I add The float:right; into The .nav Css, the Header disappears.

Any Fixes?

Is It An Over Flow Problem?

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    background: #008000;
    width: 100%;
    top:0px;
    position fixed;
}

.logo{
    float:left;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size: 15px;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

li{
    list-style:none;
}

.nav{    
    float:right;           //Right Here Is Where It Breaks    
}  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fixed Header & Nav</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="Style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">    
        <div class="container">   
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">Website</h1>
            </div>   
            <div class ="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="content">
        <p>Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo 
        Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo   
        Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo 
        Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo           
        Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo Thuggo Puggo <p>     
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's not a such problem at all.

You just forgot the ":" after the 'position' command, so all your css style will get broken after that

```
.header {
     background: #008000;
     width: 100%;
     top:0px;
     position fixed; /* <--- It's here where you have to put a ':' after the position */
}
```

Replace the code above to the correct below:

```
.header {
    background: #008000;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px; 
    position: fixed; /* Now it's should works */
}
```

I think that would be a good tip if you check the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170184/is-css-giving-error) that talks about css errors. CSS is not a programming language, every browser has an **inbuilt CSS interpreter/parser** following [W3C standards](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html), but if the interpreter finds a error its gonna be ignored.

### Use a IDE or a text editor

Try to use some IDE like Intellij, Eclipse and Webstorm or even a simple text editor that provides you a just in time error checker:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use text-align: right, in .nav instead of float.

[text-align: right result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7I1u.jpg)

Comment: Thank You Very Much